# Why does azure CLI not return the same data I see in the portal for Application Insights logs?

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql, azure-log-analytics

I'm querying my Azure Application Insights logs to find the number of failed requests within an hour of a release:

```
let startTime = datetime_local_to_utc(datetime('2023-07-12 16:22:18'),"Canada/Eastern");
requests
| where timestamp >= startTime and timestamp <= startTime + 1h
| where success == false
| summarize FailedRequestsCount = count()
| extend StartTimeUTC = format_datetime(startTime, 'yy-MM-dd h:mm tt')
```

When I run this query in the Monitoring -> Logs section of my Application Insights instance, I get results like this: [screenshot of kql output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MMK1.png)

but when I run the same query from azure CLI, I see no results:

```
az monitor app-insights query --resource-group XXXXXX --app [The name of the application insights instance] --start-time 2023-07-01 --analytics-query 'let startTime = datetime_local_to_utc(datetime("2023-07-27 16:47:03"),"Canada/Eastern");
requests
| where success == false'
```

What could be causing this discrepancy?

I've tried querying all results, and modifying the start time. I'm never able to get the same data I see in the portal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide both the `--start-time` and `--end-time` parameters for the complete range. [Otherwise, the `--offset` is used](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli-extensions/blob/639e10fa4cd4656803000071dcb7fa9a301d9388/src/application-insights/azext_applicationinsights/util.py#L36) which defaults to `1h`.

So, in your command, the time range that is being used is `(startTime, startTime + 1h)`.